# React (react-native-modalize) not working with flatListProps object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, jsx, react-native-modal

Is anyone using react-native-modalize module?

**react-native-modalize** module, when i render code on flatListProps object its showing the error below!!

Here is the example as well https://jeremybarbet.github.io/react-native-modalize/#/EXAMPLES

[image]

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Modalize } from 'react-native-modalize';

export const App = () => {
  const modalizeRef = useRef<Modalize>(null);

  const onOpen = () => {
    modalizeRef.current?.open();
  };
  const arrayData = [ { "heading": "test"}, {"heading": "test2"}... ]
  let data = { "object": [arrayData] }

  const getData = () => ({ data });

  const renderItem = (item) => (
    <View>
      <Text>{item.heading}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onOpen}>
        <Text>Open the modal</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <Modalize
        ref={modalizeRef}
        flatListProps={{
          data: getData(),
          renderItem: renderItem,
          keyExtractor: item => item.heading,
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator: false,
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` of `flatListProps` is an array object.

```
    let data = { "object": [arrayData] }

    const getData = () => ([ ...data.object ]);
```

Comment: can you post the content of arrayData?

Comment: it should be something like this 
[ 
 { "heading": "test"}, {"heading": "test2"}...
]

Comment: why don't you use arrayData directly?
...
data: arrayData
...

Comment: and it should be let data = { "object": [...arrayData] }

Comment: I already tried that, same issue. thank you for youre answers

Found the solution (functional components needs to be as a forwardRef)